# Mail.app doesn't show the email body on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mail.app

Sometimes *Mail.app* doesn't show the body of the mails. It appears just for a second under the sender and the objects but then it disappears.

When I close and reopen the App the problem is fixed (sometimes it requires several relaunches). The body of the mail is also shown if I double click on the mail and open it in a separated window.

I'm using the latest version of OsX and I've installed the plugin *Mail Act-On 2.4.2*.
Mail.app is configured for

How is it possible to fix this problem?

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed with the latest updates

Comment: Mail.app 7.3, 1878.2 here, I have exactly the same symptom! It's getting me crazy!